# One liner to limit Array of Words to less than N number of characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

What's the simplest way to limit an array of words such that the resulting array, when the words are joined, is less than 40 characters?  Something that acts like this:

```
words = ["ruby", "rails", "jquery", "javascript", "html"]
words.join.length #=> 29
words.join(", ").length #=> 37
words = ["ruby", "rails", "jquery", "javascript", "html", "css", "api"]
words.join.length #=> 35
words.join(", ").length #=> 47
words.chunk(:max_chars => 40) #=> ["ruby", "rails", "jquery", "javascript", "html"]
```

**Update**

Got this so far:

```
def chop(array, separator = "", max = 40)
  result = []
  array.each do |word|
    break if (result.join(separator).length + word.length > max)
    result << word 
    result
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Do you want a partial word for the last word?

Comment: all whole words that are within the max_chars limit

Comment: You can remove the `result` you have after `result << word` and it will still work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too bad there is a fencepost condition, otherwise this would be a much cleaner code with the `take_while` method

```
def chop(array, separator = "", max_size = 40)
  so_far = 0
  sep = separator.size
  array.take_while{|word| (so_far += word.size + sep) <= max_size + sep }
end
```

It checks it is less or equals than `max_size + sep` to compensate we are adding a separator to every word, even though the last one doesn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun way, you need active support:

```
require 'active_support'
class Array
  def chunk(sep = "", max = 40)
    self.inject([]){|m,n| (m+[n]).sum(&:size)+sep.size*m.size-1<max ? m<<n : m}
  end
end
```

Now:

```
["ruby", "rails", "jquery", "javascript", "html", "css", "api"].chunk(", ") #=> ["ruby", "rails", "jquery", "javascript", "html"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on yours:

```
result = input.inject([]){|r,word|r<<word if r*separator+word.length < max}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def chop(arr, sep = "", max = 40)
  max += sep.size
  arr.take_while{|x| (max -= x.size + sep.size) >= 0 }
end
```